# Error message when writing to gpkg

Tags: pyqgis

I am writing the output of a run.processing() function to a geopackage. However, when I run the script, an error message appears indicating thathte layer was not generated correctly. Further, it indicates: "You can check the 'Log messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm"

However, the Log Message Panel is empty ! No errors or message are shown as a result of running the script. Further, I see that the gpkg was saved and after reviewing the output, it looks okay.

Why am I getting the error?
QGIS 3.16.14

```
alg_params = {
            'FIELDS_MAPPING': [{'expression': parameters['ETCCOMMID'],'length': 0,'name': 'CommNum','precision': 0,'type': 6},
            {'expression': parameters['ETCNAMEEN'],'length': 150,'name': 'Name_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': parameters['ETCNAMEFR'],'length': 150,'name': 'Name_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': parameters['ETCPROVINCE'],'length': 2,'name': 'Province','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': parameters['ETCLATITUDE'],'length': 0,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': parameters['ETCLONGITUDE'],'length': 0,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': parameters['ETCSATDEP'], 'length': 15, 'name': 'SatDep', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}],
            'INPUT': parameters['EligibleTransportCommunities'],
            #'OUTPUT': parameters['Eligible_Transport_Communities_En_Short']
            'OUTPUT': "ogr:dbname='c:/Users/nganj/Desktop/TEST/sampleOutput.gpkg' table=\"layerName\" (geom) sql="
        }
        outputs['RefactorETCToEnglishShort'] = processing.run('native:refactorfields', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
```

Comment: Error messages and code should be posted as text, not as a screenshot. It is very difficult to read for some users and impossible for screen readers, and google. Please take the [tour] to see how this site works.